# Копировать и вставить файл в android

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. На карте памяти есть файл `file.txt`. Как с помощью Java переместить его в другую папку? То есть сейчас файл в папке `FolderA`, а нужно, чтобы он оказался в папке `FolderB`.

```
File source = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/FolderA/file.txt");
File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/FolderB/file.txt");
```

Нужно сделать что-то вроде того:

```
CopyFile(source, destination);
public void CopyFile(File ОТКУДА, File КУДА) {...}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void copyFile(File sourceFile, File destFile) throws IOException {
    if(!destFile.exists()) {
        destFile.createNewFile();
    }

    FileChannel source = null;
    FileChannel destination = null;

    try {
        source = new FileInputStream(sourceFile).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(destFile).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
    }
    finally {
        if(source != null) {
            source.close();
        }
        if(destination != null) {
            destination.close();
        }
    }
}
```