# Как перезаписать файл бд

Tags: java, android

Есть такая задача: с сервера получить файл базы данных(в формате .db) и перезаписать старый файл на новый.

Пробую так:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers,
                                      File file) {
    if (statusCode != 200) {
        Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getText(R.string.error),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    Log.v(TAG, "response - success - " + file);

    try {
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
        String outputFile = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("name_db"));
        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
        int i;
        while ((i = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
             output.write(buffer, 0, i);
        }
        output.flush();
        output.close();
        input.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    pd.cancel();
}
```

Но это не работает. Как лучше это реализовать?

На всякий случай код на отправку файла бд на сервер:

```
 RequestParams params_ = new RequestParams();
 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient(true, 80, 443);

 Context context = getApplicationContext();

 File dbFile = new File(String.valueOf(context.getDatabasePath("name_db")));

 try {
      params_.put("db", dbFile);
 } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
      Log.v(TAG, "error - file not found");
 }

 client.post("example.com", params_, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header[] headers, JSONObject json) {
             Log.v(TAG, "response -- " + json);
             try {
                  if (0 == json.getInt("status")) {
                      Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getText(R.string.successfully),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, getResources().getText(R.string.error),
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  }
              } catch (JSONException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              pd.cancel();
         }
   });
```

**P.S.** Попробовал вот так:

```
(new DB(getApplicationContext())).close();

File aFile = file;
String path = String.valueOf(getApplicationContext().getDatabasePath("targ‌​ets_db")) + ".db";
if (aFile.renameTo(new File(path))) {
    Log.v(TAG, "File is moved successful!");
}
```

В логах пишет, что файл был перемещен, но однако файл бд не изменился на нужный(бекапешный).

Comment: Вы уверены что хотите каждый получать новый файл? А не получать данные за какой-то период и временно их кешировать локально?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442228/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-android

Comment: @AstendSanferion, попробовал - не помогло

Comment: @КириллМатасов, суть такая - я сделал бекап бд себе на сервер, потом, если что-то пошло бы не так, я мог восстановить бд из бекапа на сервере.

Comment: Что значит не работает? В LogCat смотрели, ошибки есть? Если база на момент перезаписи уже открыта, нужно закрыть.

Comment: @woesss, ошибок нет, а вот база вроде была не закрыта. Сейчас проверю

Comment: @woesss, закрыл бд так - `(new DB(getApplicationContext())).close();`. Однако это не помогло.

Comment: Это что за финт ушами ))) Вы свою открытую закройте. Ещё не внушает доверия такой буфер `new byte[input.available()]` - лучше используйте конкретный размер, и в условии цикла нужно проверять на `!= -1`, так как `0` может вернуться в любом месте потока

Comment: Я нуб пока в андроид разработке) У меня махинации с заменой бд идут в `SettingsActivity`, а работа с бд(вывод записей) в `MainActivity`. Т.е., если я правильно понимаю, то бд у меня закрыта в `SettingsActivity`.

Comment: @woesss, как правильно будет все это реализовать?