# Копирование ArrayList во внешнее хранилище

Tags: java, android, io

Как можно копировать `ArrayList` в внешнее хранилище, чтобы это было доступно пользователю.

Нашёл 2 похожие темы, но не помогло.

[Тема 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/533801/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-sqlite-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8F-%D0%B1%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D1%8C)
[Тема 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442228/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D0%B2-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileOutputStream os = null;
 try {
    os = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/sample.txt");
    os.write(dataToSave);
    os.flush();
    os.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}`

Answer (score 0):

Сохраните в преференсы:

```
SharedPreferences prefs;
ArrayList<String> myList; //лист который надо сохранить
//blah-blah
SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
Set<String> sets=new HashSet<String>(myList); //конвертируем в Set<>
editor.putStringSet("myList", sets); //пихаем сет в префы
editor.commit(); //записываем
```

Answer (score 0):

Сначала находите это самое внешнее хранилище:

```
File externalRootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Потом создаете в нем файл:

```
File logFile = new File(externalRootDir , "Log.txt");
```

Далее записываете в него содержимое `ArrayList`:

```
try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(logFile)) {
    for (String data : dataList) {
        printWriter.println(data);
    }
}
```

**UPD**:

Конструкция `try-with-resources` появилась в Java 7. В меньших версиях можно вот так:

```
PrintWriter printWriter = null;

try {
    printWriter = new PrintWriter(logFile);
    for (String data : dataList) {
        printWriter.println(data);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (printWriter != null) {
        printWriter.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @posr_zeew В строке try (PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(logFile)),   logFile выделяет красным, но я его описал 
и в следующей строке подчёркивает красным String data

Comment: @MaxProvy, Смотрите **UPD**. Так же не забудьте про runtime permissions.

Comment: Я `File externalRootDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();` и `File logFile = new File(externalRootDir , "Log.txt");` написал в метод OnCreate, остальной код в мною созданный метод, но студия выделяет ошибки. [Скрин](https://pp.userapi.com/c834200/v834200772/23db3/80et-cGTP1o.jpg)

Comment: @MaxProvy, Какие ошибки?

Comment: я переместил первые две строки, чтобы они описывались в классе, а не в методах.
В строке new PrintWriter(logFile) подчёркивает красным и пишет Unhandled exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException
И следующая ошибка Incompatible types. Required: Object 
Found: String